# How to Automatically Execute RunWorkerAsync When a Progress Form is Displayed

Tags: c#, forms, asynchronous, backgroundworker

For my application, I need to have a progress bar form for a long running data enveloping job/big OpenXML Excel file write, so I have created a "pop-up" form called "RunEnvelope_Form". It is simple and contains a progress bar, status box, cancel button and close button. I am utilizing a Background worker to do the heaving data enveloping/Excel file write work which is working fine.

In order to have the BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync execute automatically I have added it to the end of the Shown event of the RunEnvelope_Form (which *SEEMED* like a good idea). The BackgroundWorker executes successfully, but I have a few problems:

[1] The progress window cannot be moved
[2] Most importantly the Cancel button is unresponsive until after the RunWorkerCompleted event is executed.

Thinking about it, makes sense since I suspect the main form has not entered the message loop yet?

**So my question is**, what is the best way to start RunWorkerAsync automatically when a form is displayed? I really really want to avoid a start button which seems to be the norm in the examples on MSDN I have come across.

This is how I display the form from my main application window:

```
DialogResult dr = EnvelopeResults.ShowDialog();
```

And this is the Shown event in the RunEnvelope_Form form (note all of the Worker thread machinery is setup in the constructor for the form):

```
private void RunEnvelope_Form_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)    
        {  
        // GUI setup  

        CanceAsyncButton_Click.Enabled = true;  
        CloseFormOKButton_Click.Enabled = false;  
        Status_Label.Text = ""; 
        EnvelopeProgress_Bar.Value = 0; 
        EnvelopeProgress_Bar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;  
        EnvelopeProgress_Bar.ForeColor = Color.Green;  

        // setup a tuple to handle input data to worker thread (I like Tuples)  

        Tuple<AnalysisSeries, Dictionary<int, bool>, string> aysncData =  
            new Tuple<AnalysisSeries, Dictionary<int, bool>, string>  
            (_Aseries, _CasestoRender, _OutputXLS);  

        // now can start the envelope process  

        EnvelopeResults_Worker.RunWorkerAsync(aysncData);  
    }
```

Comment: Could be wrong, but I'm not sure your assumption that the Shown event handler never ends is correct. However, it's very easy to check. Add a Debug.WriteLine statement at the end of that code, and watch the Output window to see if it gets hit. Or just add a breakpoint on the closing brace, would serve the same purpose. If it does get hit, then you'd know that's not your problem. If it doesn't, then at least you know what the problem is

Comment: Avrohom, I did as you suggested and confirmed that indeed the code stalls at RunWorkerAsync. I was just hoping that the message loop would already be running in the Shown event.

Comment: Can you post more of your code, specifically, the bit where the BW is set up? I cna't see any reason why this wouldn't work, but would like to see more. Please post enough for me to be able to try it here